# Django - Naive datetime field to time zone

Tags: django, time

I'm using `Django` to build an web app and I have a shift in datetime datas when I upload them.
In `settings.py` I specify :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'CET'
USE_TZ = True
```

In `models.py` I have :

```
class my_table(MyModel):

    # Value of the timeserie entry
    value = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=20,
        decimal_places=4,
        null=False
    )

    # Date of the timeserie entry
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        null=False       
    )
```

When I upload data like `29/01/2024  14:00:00` , I have this message :

```
DateTimeField my_table.date received a naive datetime while time zone support is active
```

In the `PostgreSQL` database, datas are stored in `UTC` not `CET`, in my example:

`2024-01-29 13:00:00+00`

Django interpret naive datetime in `UTC` not in `CET (UTC+1)` despite my `settings.py TIME_ZONE` parameter.

EDIT: To complete my question, after parsing datas and loading them into a `pandas dataframe`, I'm using an handler to save them into database. This one convert `dataframe` to `dict`, and I'm understanding that datetime values are assigned a `UTC` time zone by default.

```
# Converting df to dict to prepare parsing
df_measures = df.to_dict('records', index=True)
```

When I print the output I have

```
[{'value': 0.0, 'date': Timestamp('2024-01-29 13:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')}]
```

I need to find where `tz='UTC'` is defined or if it's a value by default.

How can I define that datas are `CET` and store `2024-01-29 13:00:00+01` ?

Comment: Can you share the view where you create such records (in the `my_table`)?

Comment: For sure, I edited my post to add `models.py`

Comment: But how does the view looks like that creates the records?

Comment: I have completed my question